# Calculating Pi using a while loop and recursive method (Java)

Tags: java, recursion, while-loop, pi

My assignment was to calculate Pi using an algorithm he gave us in class, determine correct digits, and estimate Pi to six digits using a while loop and a recursive method. But my "super smart professor" didn't tell us a bloody thing about recursive methods and when I email him, he gets angry at me for not getting it just by looking at it. This is my code so far, I left out my while loop method and recursive method because I have no idea how to do those.

```
public static final double REAL_PI = 3.14159;//PI is the value prof gave us on the handout
public static double Pi = 0; //Pi is the value of Pi that this program calculates
public static int m = 0; 

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Algorithm(); //calls on method of calculating pi
    System.out.println("Calculated pi: " + Pi); //prints out pi
    countDigits(Pi); //calls on countdigits method
    System.out.println("Number of digits: " + c); //has the computer print out the count because that's how many digits are the same
    PiRecur(); //calls on estimate digits method
}

public static double Algorithm() //should return a double (pi)
{
    for(m=1; m<=100000; m++)
    {
        Pi += 4*(Math.pow(-1, m-1)/((2*m)-1));//Math.pow uses math package to calculate a power to use the algorithm
    }
    return Pi;
}

public static int countDigits (double Pi)
{
    int a = (int) Pi; //the int cast makes Pi and REAL_PI into integers so the program can compare each digit separately 
    int b = (int) REAL_PI;
    int c = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while(a == b)//if m less then or equal to 100,000 then while loop runs
    {
        count ++;
        a = (int) (Pi*(Math.pow(10,count))); //if a=b then the computer will multiply Pi and REAL_PI by 10 
        b = (int) (REAL_PI*(Math.pow(10,count)));
        /*when you input a and b 
         * while loop compares them
         * if a = b then loop continues until a doesn't equal b and loop ends
         */
    }
    c = count; //gives c the value of the count so it can be used outside the method
    return count;
}
```

}

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: how do you estimate pi to 6 digits using a while loop and a recursive method using a different algorithm?

Comment: Please stick to Java naming conventions. This code incomprehensible - methods should be in `camelCase`. Pascal case is reserved for classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how a solution that uses a `while` loop and recursion would loop like, since I can't read your professor's mind, but I can think of two different solutions that use one or the other.

Using `while` loop :

You don't run your algorithm an arbitrary number of iterations (100000 in your example) and hope that you got close enough to the expected result. You use a `while` loop, and on each iteration you check if your current calculation of Pi is close enough to your target.

```
public static double Algorithm()
{
    int m = 1;
    double Pi = 0.0;
    while (countDigits(Pi) < 6) {
        Pi += 4*(Math.pow(-1, m-1)/((2*m)-1)); // I'm assuming this formula works
        m++;
    }
    return Pi;
}
```

Using recursion :

The same solution can be translated into a recursion. This time, you supply an initial index `m` (1) and an initial value of `Pi` (0) to `Algorithm`. The method adds the `m`'th term to `Pi`. If the new value of `Pi` is not good enough (determined by `countDigits`), you make a recursive call that would add the `m+1`th term to `Pi` and check again if the new value is good enough. The recursion would stop when the value of `Pi` is 6 digits accurate.

```
public static double Algorithm(int m,double Pi)
{
    Pi += 4*(Math.pow(-1, m-1)/((2*m)-1));
    if (countDigits(Pi) < 6)
        Pi += Algorithm(m+1,Pi);

    return Pi;
}
```

You call the method with :

```
Algorithm (1,0.0);
```

Comment: the recursive method keeps giving me a stack overflow error for the if statement

Comment: @KazuoKatiushi Stack overflow means the recursion doesn't stop. I can't see any obvious bug just looking at the code. You should try to add some debug prints or run the method with a debugger, and see how the value of Pi changes with each recursive call.

Comment: The formula is correct. Just be sure to start from 1; starting from 0 will yield pi + 4 instead of pi.

Comment: yea I just went through and found it starting from 0 and threw off my code a bit but thanks for helping me out!!